# Displaying fetch data in dynamic fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am generating these dynamic fields using Jquery and storing their data in JSON format for invoice record, and I want to display the stored data back in these fields after fetching from the database for the update process.
Please help how can I do that?

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
        <div class="box-tools">
              <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary tableaction" data-action="add"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Add More Items</button>
              <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tableaction" data-action="remove"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus"></i> Remove Last One</button>
            </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr.#</th>
            <th>ITEM DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th>HSN/SAC Code</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="invoiceitems">
            <tr class="invoiceitemdetail">
              <td class="sno">1</td> 
              <td><?=form_input(array('name' => 'itemdesc[]','id' => 'itemdesc','type' => 'text','class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Enter detail','value' => set_value('itemdesc[]')))?></td>
              <td><?=form_input(array('name' => 'saccode[]','id' => 'saccode[]','type' => 'text','class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Enter SAC Code','value' => set_value('saccode[]')))?></td>
              <td><?=form_input(array('name' => 'units[]','id' => 'units[]','type' => 'text','class' => 'form-control inputcalqty','placeholder' => 'Enter Quantity','value' => set_value('units[]')))?></td>
              <td><?=form_input(array('name' => 'quantities[]','id' => 'quantities[]','type' => 'text','class' => 'form-control inputcalunit','placeholder' => 'Enter Units','value' => set_value('quantities[]')))?></td>
              <td><?=form_input(array('name' => 'rates[]','id' => 'rates[]','type' => 'text','class' => 'form-control inputcalprice','placeholder' => 'Enter Price','value' => set_value('rates[]')))?></td>
              <td><?=form_input(array('name' => 'amount[]','id' => 'amount[]','type' => 'text','class' => 'form-control inputtotalamount','placeholder' => 'Total Amount','value' => set_value('amount[]')))?></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<script>
        $('button[data-action="remove"]').hide();
        $('#invoicecreation').on('click','.tableaction',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          //console.log(appendctrl);
          $('button[data-action="remove"]').show();
          var dataact= $(this).data('action');
          var totaltablerecords = $('.invoiceitemdetail').length;
          var appendctrl = $('.invoiceitemdetail').eq(0).clone().find("input").val("").end();
          if(dataact === 'add'){
            $(appendctrl).appendTo('.invoiceitems');  
          }else if(dataact === 'remove'){
            if(totaltablerecords > 1){
              $('.invoiceitemdetail:last-child').remove();
              if($('.invoiceitemdetail').length ==1){
                $('button[data-action="remove"]').hide();
              }
            }else{
              $('button[data-action="remove"]').hide();
            }
          }
          $("td.sno").each(function(index,element){                 
            $(element).text(index + 1); 
          });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: `json_decode()` the stored json string, then loop through it and for your inputs do `set_value('itemdesc[0]', $default_value);` - increment the `index` of `itemdesc[]` accordingly.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what this json string looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use server side script like php to get data on new page and convert it into json. Loop using jquery loop functionality and append data on UI

Comment: thanks for you reply, same is done by me aprox 10 month before